# How to estimate the error of a numerical solution of the Laplace equation?

Tags: harmonic-functions, computational-mathematics, estimation

Let's say there is a numerical solution of the Laplace equation that was obtained using some complicated or unknown way, and we wish to estimate the error of this solution.

What would be a good way to do this?

I think we can start by plugging in the numerical solution into the Laplace equation, but then we obtain the error for the Laplacian of the function. We can then multiply it by the square of the area or volume of the function domain to estimate the error in the function itself.

Is that it, or is there a more standard or preferable method?

Comment: The description "obtained in using some complicated way" does not admit much in the way of analysis.  For standard methods (finite difference, finite elements) the usual way of getting [a posteriori error estimates](https://www.math.uni-sb.de/ag/fuchs/Menupkte/SB01.pdf) is by recomputing the solution on a finer discetization and determining how much the solution changes.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks! -- the link is quite helpful. Since the numerical solution is obtained using a complicated "black-box" method, this places limitations on the error analysis, but I think something can be done nevertheless.